# How to ensure that type parameters are different in Scala?

Tags: generics, scala

With the following definition it's possible to ensure the concrete type parameters are equal:

```
trait WithEqual[T1 >: T2 <: T2, T2]
```

So the line

```
type A = WithEqual[Int, Int]
```

will be legal. Now my question is: How to achieve exactly the opposite? Thus, the following line should *not* compile:

```
type B = WithUnequal[Int, Int]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is pretty tricky in Scala, you have to resort to intentional ambiguity. Here's an [example](http://gist.github.com/477110) of this technique.

Mark Harrah has generalized the trick in his playground for type-level hackery, [Up](http://github.com/harrah/up/blob/master//Contains.scala).

It's likely that this could be applied to your question, but I haven't the time to try right now.